# Strongest Online Integral Calculator

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a question meant for the whole community, or at least for those who have taken Calculus before. In general, which website possess the highest powered calculator for evaluating Integrals? I am looking for something that won't return a "Standard Computation Time Exceeded" when I type a tricky or difficult integral, but also a calculator that is free of charge. I'm open to hearing any or all answers and I know this question is subjective, but please, bear with me.

More specifically, I am looking for an online calculator that does not require me to use a programming language such as Java or C++. I have always used Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica to evaluate integrals but I was wondering if there were calculators that were even stronger than that. To narrow down the list of possible options, I would like to reiterate that I am not looking for a calculator that costs money or requires a programming language to use.

Comment: I believe http://fricas.sourceforge.net/ (or Axiom) is very good with integrals, and one can use it via Sage mentioned in an answer.

Comment: FriCAS: http://fricas-wiki.math.uni.wroc.pl/SandBoxFriCAS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try some of these :

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com)

[SageMathCell](http://sagecell.sagemath.org)

[Maxima-online](http://maxima-online.org)

[Magma Calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)