# Powerful integral calculators

Tags: calculus, integration

I am looking for an online calculator which can compute integrals using different methods such as the Trapezoid rule, Simpson's rule and the rectangular rule. I have been using https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-2/ until now. But, it is only able to calculate integrals when the number of divisions ($n$) is less than $200$.

Are there any other calculators which can compute integrals with a larger number of divisions?

Note: I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891774/strongest-online-integral-calculator) answer. Sagemathcell seems to be down and WolframAlpha doesn't seem to be taking custom parameters like the method used for approximatin and $n$.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Wolfram for this task. We can perform customised [Simpson's rule](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos(x)+%2B+x%5E3+using+Simpson%27s+rule+with+interval+width+0.25+from+x+%3D+0+to+3), [trapezoidal rule](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos(x)+%2B+x%5E3+using+trapezoid+rule+with+interval+width+0.25+from+x+%3D+0+to+3) and [rectangular rule](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos(x)+%2B+x%5E3+using+rectangular+rule+with+interval+width+0.25+from+x+%3D+0+to+3).

Comment: While Wolfram Alpha probably doesn't allow to set different integration methods (**see the comment above, it does**), its parent software, Mathematica, does. The `NIntegrate[]` function has the `Method` option which allows us to specify almost any parameter for numerical integration. I know that most, if not all, functions of Mathematica can be used on Wolfram Cloud for free, provided you register. I haven't tried that myself

Comment: If you really want to try out different methods of numerical integration, I suggest picking any programming language and writing your own simple code

Comment: Another advice: look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature, it's much more interesting and useful provided the function can be closely approximated by a polynomial

Comment: Thanks @PeterForeman and @YuriyS! I was able to write a program that calculates an integral using the rectangular formula. It is quite fast. I will try other methods too.